# agm-map' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have created simple angular project in Angular 12. I am trying to add google map search box and map in my project. I have followed [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-google-maps-with-places-search-exampleexample.html).

For step 4 and step 5 from that link I have created new component and applied html and ts code in its files. I have `app-routing.module.ts, app.module.ts`. No other modules.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CscdropdownComponent } from './components/cscdropdown/cscdropdown.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { GooglemapComponent } from './components/googlemap/googlemap.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CscdropdownComponent,
    GooglemapComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'API Key',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting error on its html file as below:
[image]

I did not find any solution for this. Please help and guide me. Thanks

Comment: It does not support Angular 12.
Last time it was updated before 1 year.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi is there any other way I can add google maps in angular 12?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps

Comment: sorry maybe it can work agm-map for V12, see the code here.
https://remotestack.io/how-to-implement-google-maps-in-angular-application/